# Get data from mysqli from 2 databases

Tags: php, pdo

i have a search and 2 databases. When i click search button i get data like search query from mysql. And it shows all results like that:

first answers i am getting from 1 database and seacond part of answers i am getting from 2 db.

how do i combine 2 answers into one so i need to take data from 2 dbs in one       query. But when i am taking data from mysql i am taking like that: $query = $db->prepare(query...); but i need like that
 $query = $db->$db2->prepare(query...); How i can do this but right.

```html
$query = $db2->prepare("SELECT * FROM mikro_wiki WHERE blog_title LIKE '%$search%' OR description LIKE '%$search%' OR category LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $starting_limit, $limit");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();


$query2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_blog WHERE blog_title LIKE '%$search%' OR description LIKE '%$search%' OR category LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY blog_title LIMIT $starting_limit, $limit");
$query2->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query2->execute();
```

I need combine this 2 querys in one

Comment: Are both DBs on the same server? Have you access to both of this DBs as the same user with the same password? Are both DBs the same? (like both are MySQL)

Comment: Are you using 2 different databases, or two different tables in the same database?  If two tables in one DB, you could use a `union` in your select statement, assuming you are pulling the same number of columns wiht the same types

Comment: @ivanivan no i am using 2 phpmyadmin dbs

Comment: @CodiMech25 yes they are on one hosting and they has different username

Comment: You are stuck making 2 calls.